# Collision detection/player movement physics

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics

I have an issue understanding and fixing an issue I am having. I have a collision map and if an element is a 1 it should trigger my collision detection function, which it does. I am pretty sure my problem exist with how I am controlling my characters movement but I can't figure out what to do to fix it. If I hit a wall I can still move through it even though I set `player.vx` to `0`. So then I added `player.x = cell.x - cell.w` but doing that for all sides causes the character to be flung around depending on which side gets called first in my routing table.

I have also tried many many variations of adding velocity to my player to prevent the unwanted penetration.

Here's my players code

```
let friction = 0.9;
let gravity = 2;
let size = 32;
//player
class Player {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 256;
        this.y = 96;
        this.w = 32;
        this.h = 32;
        this.vx = 0;
        this.vy = 0;
        this.oldX = this.x;
        this.oldY = this.y;
        this.jumping = false;
    }
    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h)
    }
    update() {
      this.oldX = this.x;
      this.oldY = this.y;
      if (controller.right) {this.vx += 1}
      if (controller.left) {this.vx -= 1}
      if (controller.up && !this.jumping) {this.vy -= 10; this.player = true}
      if (controller.down) {this.vy += 1}
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        this.vx *= friction;
        this.vy *= friction;
        this.vy += gravity;
        this.draw();
    }
}
let player = new Player();
```

and a Codepen to make it easier to help https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/GRrjXGE?editors=0010

thanks in advance

EDIT: If anyone finds this I left a new CodePen in the comments below with a working example completely re-written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Alright I think I got it

[image]

First off, it looks like `leftCollision()` and `rightCollision()` functions have the names mixed up.

The `if` conditional statements in both functions look correct to me, so I decided to rejected the new `x` value by assigning the `oldX` value to it:

```
function rightCollision(obj, cell) {
    if (obj.x + obj.w >= cell.x && obj.oldX < obj.x) {
        obj.vx = 0;
        obj.x = obj.oldX;    // <-- like this
    } 
};
```

---

#### How I approached debugging this

1. Focused on a single direction. I chose moving right
2. Noticed that it's detecting the left collision only after hitting the left arrow key
3. Printed the player and cell coordinates inside RightCollision() and noticed that the `x` and `oldX` 'seemed' correct to me
4. Rejected the new `x` value by assigning the `oldX` value to it.

Comment: That seems to be a step in the right direction. One issue is if I do that to the Y also then when I walk across the top of the boxes the player vibrates and moves slowly.

Comment: It solves two of the three problems that you posted. The vibrating has to do with your vy being reset inside of `update()` function, so your `this.vy = 0` isn't doing the effect you're expecting

Comment: Looks like you applied this solution in your codepen, so this might be good for an accepted answer here. What do you think @Justin?

Comment: It does take care of the x and y. Now I need to figure out the rest. I feel like this should be much easier. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've gone a completely different route and tried a new approach. I am now calculating the distance of all four sides and using that to assist with the CD between tiles. I also added a function to limit the distance from player that tiles will be calculated to save on performance. It's currently set to 2 and I have also added the distance vectors for visualization purposes. Here's a CodePen https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/jOymVKK?editors=0010